# Load XML in table (SQL) and Query

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle, oracle10g

I've googled but can't seem to find a straight answer. I have a simple table in which I loaded the content of a complete XML file. Now I try to query the XML data and give it a structured overview, THIS WORKS, but I need some explanation.

**My question (see used data below):**

- Can someone explain how I can extend my query, so I can also query data from the XML section 'AddressC'. Right now I can only get the data from 'AddressB'.
- What in the world does this part do, and why is there an url (i've copied the query from the internetz): **xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi")**

***XML in table (XML_FILES2, table has tow cells test1 and test2):***

```
<PurchaseOrder>
  <AddressB>
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Addressb>
  <AddressC>
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </AddressC>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

***And the Query I use***

```
SELECT street
FROM xml_files2 xf, xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi"),
'PurchaseOrder/Addressb' passing xf.test2
columns 
street varchar2(100) path 'Street'
) PurchaseOrder;
```

Comment: XML handling in databases isn't (so far as I'm aware) standardized -  what database system are you using?

Comment: I suppose you're using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid XML.  The closing tag Addressb does not match the opening tag AddressB.

In case that's just a typo in your question, here's an example on reading the Street element from various parents in XML.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (C1 XMLTYPE);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (XMLTYPE('<PurchaseOrder>
  <AddressB>
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </AddressB>
  <AddressC>
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </AddressC>
</PurchaseOrder>'));


SELECT STREET FROM T1, XMLTABLE('PurchaseOrder/*' PASSING T1.C1 
    COLUMNS 
        STREET VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'Street'
    ) PURCHASEORDER;
```

Result:

```
STREET                                                                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123 MAPLE STREET                                                                                     
8 Oak Avenue
```